# How to apply limitations into all of business points in spring/hibernate enterprise application without change codes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, business-logic

Assume this class diagram:

[image]

I have class named `Organization` that many objects has association to that. also there are many object in addition to the `StoreHouse` and `Personnel`, but to have simple class diagram, i didn't put those classes into diagram (assume more than 1000 classes are depended to `Organization` class).

Now, i want to add `enabled` field to the `Organization` class. it's very simple and there isn't any problem. but after that, i want to prevent all business points and services to use `disabled` organizations.

for example assume this below service:

```
@Service
public class PersonnelService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonnelRepository repository;

    public long save(Personnel entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

If i had above code in the application, after add `enabled` field to `Organization`, i should change above method to this:

```
@Service
public class PersonnelService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonnelRepository repository;

    public long save(Personnel entity) {

        if(!entity.getOrganization().getEnabled()) {
            throw Exception();
        }

        return repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

And because of this action is very time consuming, to change more than 1,000 classes.
I want to know is there a way to this action without changing business point, for example with using Aspect or something like it, and detect when the modification are making on the object and it have a field with type of `Organization` check the `enabled` value?

Comment: Define a `@Where` on the organization which filters on the `enabled` attribute. That way the disabled organizations are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you are using spring data jpa or spring data rest to achieve update. If so then this can be achieved as follows:

Create an annotation UpdateIfTrue

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface UpdateIfTrue {
    String value();
}
```

Create a service

```
@Service("updateIfTrueService")
public class UpdateIfTrueService {

    public boolean canUpdate(Object object){

        Class klass = object.getClass();
        UpdateIfTrue updateIfTrue = (UpdateIfTrue) klass.getAnnotation(UpdateIfTrue.class);
        if (updateIfTrue != null){
            String propertyTree[] = updateIfTrue.value().split(".");

            /*Traverse heirarchy now to get the value of the last one*/
            int i=0;
            try{
                while(i<propertyTree.length){
                    for (Field field : klass.getDeclaredFields()){
                        if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(propertyTree[i])){
                            if (i < (propertyTree.length - 1)){
                                i++;
                                klass = field.getClass();
                                object = field.get(object);
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (i == (propertyTree.length - 1)){
                                i++;
                                klass= field.getClass();
                                object = field.get(object);
                                return (Boolean)object;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Annotate the entity that you want to be checked. e.g., User with following annotation

```
@UpdateIfTrue("personnel.organization.enabled")
```

Now In the Repository do the following

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("@updateIfTrueService.canUpdate(#user)")
User save(@Param("user")User user);
```